# How to handle large inputs into the Text Translator Api?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I am working on a cognitive skillset in Azure Search, and I need to add Text Translator functionality to the project. Currently all of the text is translated correctly, unless the character count is above the maximum value. In which case, the api returns null.

I am currently using document/content as my input for the text translator, but I've also tried using the output of the predefined Split Skill. When I pass the files through the Split Skill (by page) before the translator skill, the indexer breaks and all of the files fail to index (even the ones that don't need to be translated)

This code taken from my skillset.json that translates all of the files below the character limit cutoff.

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
    "description": "Our new translator custom skill",
    "uri": "[my-uri]",
    "batchSize":1,
    "context": "/document",
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "text",
        "source": "/document/content"
      },
      {
        "name": "language",
        "source": "/document/languageCode"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "text",
        "targetName": "translatedText"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is my attempt to split the text by page before passing the text through the translator api. This results in a 501 error.

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
  "textSplitMode" : "pages", 
  "maximumPageLength": 4000,
  "inputs": [
  {
    "name": "text",
    "source": "/document/content"
  },
  { 
    "name": "languageCode",
    "source": "/document/languageCode"
  }
],
"outputs": [
  {
        "name": "textItems",
        "targetName": "pages"
  }
]
 }, 
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
    "description": "Our new translator custom skill",
    "uri": "[my-uri]",
    "batchSize":1,
    "context": "/document/pages/*",
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "text",
        "source": "/document/pages/*"
      },
      {
        "name": "language",
        "source": "/document/languageCode"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "text",
        "targetName": "translatedText"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I use the exact same implementation for the Named Entity Recognition Skill (using document/pages/* as input), and it works fine. I'm not sure what the difference would be with the Text Translator skill.

Comment: When you use the split skill, you mentioned calling the translator and getting a 501? Is that accurate, because that shouldn't be an error code returned by any cognitive service. Could you provide more details on what the error is?

Or alternatively, if you provide the name of your search service and the name of your indexer to which this skillset is attached, I can try taking a look and finding out the error

Comment: You were right. I just changed the index source from `"document/pages/*/tanslatedText"` to `"document/pages/*/translatedText/*"` and now I get the following error message: `"The data field 'translatedText' in the document with key 'translatedText' has an invalid value of type 'Collection(Edm.String)'. The expected type was 'Edm.String'."` Do I need to use the Merge Skill to get text into one string?

Comment: Hold on - when you say index source, you mean indexer output field mappings correct? `/document/pages/*/translatedText/*` iterates through every single element in the translatedText output (which is a string) resulting in an array of strings...

Your original skillset definition looks fine, and your output field mapping should use `/document/pages/*/translatedText` ... I want more clarity on the actual error from the translation api you are getting in the prior instance

Comment: This is the error message I get from the set up in my original question: `"Skill #5: Web API call resulted in an error. Status code from Web API call: 'InternalServerError'` Skill #5 is my translator.

Comment: Could you share the search service name and the name of the indexer, so that I could take a glance at what could be the issue?

Comment: Also I assume you were following this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-create-custom-skill-example

That page has complete code samples for the azure function. Also note that the "languageCode" needs to be the "destination" language code; i.e., the language you want things to be translated to. I cannot tell if that's the case from your skillset definition